# Python requests exceptions timeout

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, timeout

I wrote a python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import requests

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Usage: python %s <IP-LIST>" % (sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit();

InputFile = sys.argv[1]
try:
    File = open(InputFile)
    for ip in File:
        IP = ip.rstrip()
        out = requests.get("http://" + IP, timeout=5)
        out.status_code

except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print "\nKeyboardInterruption with Ctrl+c signal"
except IOError as e:
    print "The file \"%s\" does not exist!" % (sys.argv[1])
```

When url has nothing to respond the following output appears for me:

```
The file "list.txt" does not exist!
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests` uses exceptions that subclass `IOError`, which you are catching and assuming to be file not found. If you were using Python 3 you could catch the more specific `FileNotFoundError`. Here you should put an `except requests.RequestException` block *above* your `except IOError` block (or break it out into specific `requests` errors if you want.

Comment: I got it thank you.... but could you explain more about "or break it out into specific requests errors if you want" If you have example I would be thankful... :)

Comment: I only meant that there are about half a dozen exceptions in `requests`. The base exception class is `RequestException` so that will catch all of them.